# out of shared memory error when doing pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, locking, pg-dump

I have a postgres database with 3 schemas and around 1200 tables. When i try to take a schema only pg_dump of it using the command, `pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d my_test_db -s`, I sometimes get error

> ERROR:  out of shared memory 
>   HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction

This case also occurs in a random manner, when I re-run the same query, it works well. Is there any ways to overcome this

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) Also asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210499) where it's more approriate

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Just curious what makes it more appropriate there than here. I'm relatively new here and the overlap/redundancy has always puzzled me.

Comment: The error is not deterministic because it depends on the number of locks that concurrent transactions hold. You should just do what the message suggests and increase `max_locks_per_transaction`.